# Why is ASP.NET accepting externally created session identifiers?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, membership

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 Web Site using the standard SQL Membership Provider.

The application has to pass the IBM Rational AppScan before we can push to production.

I am getting the error:
Severity: High
Test Type: Application
Vulnerable URL: http://mytestserver/myapp/login.aspx
Remediation Tasks: **Do not accept externally created session identifiers**

What can I do to fix this?

I am using SQL Membership Provider. Is this related? I am using the standard login controls too. I have the "Remember Me" turned off, and hidden.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this would be inherently bad? Doesn't change the fact that they check for it, but I'm wondering *why*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a vulnerability (and I really don't like AppScan because of its false positives - the number of times I've had to explain CSRF cookies need not be linked to a session on my little open source project is getting annoying).

All that will happen in this case is the first time anything is stored in session state with a created session identifier a new session will be opened on the server, with nothing in it. If you're worried about session fixation then you can clear the cookie after authentication.

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

But with forms authentication the authentication details are not held in the session and so fixation is not a problem at all.

Frankly if you *must* pass security scans without anyone evaluating if the results are not false positives then that's a whole different problem.

Comment: Thanks. However, I tried this, but the IBM Rational AppScan reported the same security error.

Comment: It's not a vulnerability though and your explanation is wrong. You've written and accepted an incorrect answer.

Comment: I agree with you, but just saying it is not enough. I do not like the AppScan tool either, but that is the world I live in. I waste a day or so on every project. Until they change policy I have to live with it.

Comment: Wow, weird :) But glad it passed.

Comment: Question: where should I put those two lines? In `Session_End` in `Global.asax`?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to change the default cookie settings to be unique to you app

Try setting a unique cookie path:

```
<forms name="YourAppName"
       path="/FormsAuth" ... />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx#paght000012_additionalconsiderations

More reading... 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998258.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would seem [RegenerateExpiredSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.regenerateexpiredsessionid.aspx) property is controlling this. 
Do set it to true. Also keep time-out to a and low value, the tightest acceptable by users (e.g. 10 - 15 minutes).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but IBM Rational AppScan is hitting the site every few seconds. Lowering the value to 10 minutes does not help.